# libgdx pixel issues between desktop and android projects

Tags: android, libgdx

**UPDATE** Looks like this is a problem because of the static notification bar on tablet because of the lack of hardware buttons. I just didn't think about that. Anyway, in the case of the TF101 it returns a resolution of 1280x752 so about 1.702 (80 : 47) ratio. If I use a suitable unit size, like 33.5 or 11.75 vertically I get the proper scaling and this seems to fix the problem of skewed pixels.
**END UPDATE**

I've been setting up a game using 16x16 units for my tiled maps. I am using the resolution 1280x800 on both my desktop and android projects, I'm testing this to get a sense of how it will look on my TF101 asus tablet. I currently use a camera with units of 20x12.5 (wxh) and notice no pixel scaling on my desktop project, but when I run the game on my android I get weird scaling, and a green horizontal line. I can also move about quarter cell further along the x-axis on the tablet, shown in the screen shots. The pixels on the android project don't seem uniform at all.

I set the verticalTiles amount to 12.5f, then calculate the horizontalTiles amount as

```
verticalTiles = 12.5f;
...
horizontalTiles = (float) width / (float) height * verticalTiles;
camera = new OrthographicCamera(horizontalTiles, verticalTiles);
```

I'm aiming for devices with different aspect ratios to simply see more or less of the map, but can't seem to get working correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Android Capture - http://imageshack.us/f/7/dsvg.png/ - notice the highlights on the roof edges, they are not uniform at all.

Desktop Capture - http://imageshack.us/f/853/5itv.png/

Current MainGame class

```
package com.bitknight.bqex;

/* Bunch of imports */

public class MainGame implements ApplicationListener {
  private OrthographicCamera camera;
  private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
  private TiledMap map;
  private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;
  private Texture texture;
  private Texture clothArmor;
  private Sprite sprite;
  private BitmapFont font;

  private float horizontalTiles = 0;
  private float verticalTiles = 12.5f;
  private int hoverTileX = 0;
  private int hoverTileY = 0;

  private TiledMapTileLayer layer;
  private Cell cell;
  private TiledMapTile canMoveToTile;
  private TiledMapTile cannotMoveToTile;

  private AnimatedTiledMapTile animatedStopTile;
  private AnimatedTiledMapTile animatedGoTile;

  private Texture spriteSheet;
  private TextureRegion region;

  private Player player;

  float h, w;
  float ppuX, ppuY;

  @Override
  public void create() {    
    // Setup the animated tiles
    Array<StaticTiledMapTile> tileArray;
    // Start position on the sheet
    int startX = 192;
    int startY = 1568;

    spriteSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/maps/tilesheet.png"));
    spriteSheet.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
    // We are trying to load two strips of 4 frames, 8 total
    for( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
      tileArray = new Array<StaticTiledMapTile>(4);
      for( int j = 0; j < 4; ++j ) {
        region = new TextureRegion(spriteSheet, startX, startY, 16, 16);
        tileArray.add(new StaticTiledMapTile(region));
        startX += 16;
      }

      if( i == 0 ) {
        animatedStopTile = new AnimatedTiledMapTile(1/10f, tileArray);
      } else {
        animatedGoTile = new AnimatedTiledMapTile(1/10f, tileArray);
      }
    }

    // Load the map
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("data/maps/base.tmx");
    // Setup the two tiles that show movable and not movable sprites
    canMoveToTile = map.getTileSets().getTileSet(0).getTile(1959);
    canMoveToTile.setBlendMode(BlendMode.ALPHA);
    cannotMoveToTile = map.getTileSets().getTileSet(0).getTile(1958);
    cannotMoveToTile.setBlendMode(BlendMode.ALPHA);

    // Manually create the layer used to show the cursor sprites
    layer = new TiledMapTileLayer(100, 100, 16, 16);
    layer.setName("display");
    cell = new Cell();
    cell.setTile(canMoveToTile);
    layer.setOpacity(1f);
    mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1/16f);
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/consolas.fnt"), false);
    font.setScale(0.6f);

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/maps/tilesheet.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    clothArmor = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/img/native/clotharmor.png"));
    region = new TextureRegion(clothArmor, 32, 256, 32, 32);
    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setOrigin(0.5f, 0.5f);
    sprite.setPosition(0f - 0.5f, 0f);
    sprite.setSize(2, 2);

    // Setup player and associated animations
    Array<TextureRegion> regions = new Array<TextureRegion>();

    player = new Player();
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose() {
    spriteBatch.dispose();
    texture.dispose();
    clothArmor.dispose();
    spriteSheet.dispose();
  }

  @Override
  public void render() {
    player.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    camera.update();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if( Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ESCAPE) ) {
      Gdx.app.exit();
    }

    // Clear the last cell
    layer.setCell(hoverTileX, hoverTileY, null);
    // Convert screen coordinates to world coordinates
    Vector3 worldCoordinates = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(0), Gdx.input.getY(0), 0);
    camera.unproject(worldCoordinates);
    hoverTileX = (int)(worldCoordinates.x);
    hoverTileY = (int)(worldCoordinates.y);

    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get("collision");

    if( Gdx.input.isTouched(0) ) {
      //sprite.setPosition(hoverTileX - 0.5f, hoverTileY);
      player.pos.x = hoverTileX - 0.5f;
      player.pos.y = hoverTileY - 0.25f;
      cell.setTile(animatedGoTile);
    } else {
      if (layer.getCell(hoverTileX, hoverTileY) != null) {
        cell.setTile(cannotMoveToTile);
      } else {
        cell.setTile(canMoveToTile);
      }
    }
    layer.setCell(hoverTileX, hoverTileY, cell);

    mapRenderer.setView(camera);
    mapRenderer.render();

    mapRenderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
    mapRenderer.renderTileLayer(layer);
    mapRenderer.getSpriteBatch().end();

    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    player.render(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
  }

  @Override
  public void resize(int width, int height) {    
    horizontalTiles = (float) width / (float) height * verticalTiles;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(horizontalTiles, verticalTiles);
    w = width;
    h = height;
  }

  @Override
  public void pause() {
  }

  @Override
  public void resume() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please add your "update" as an answer to your question.  As a new user this may be blocked for a bit, but it should eventually be possible.  Thanks! See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a problem because of the static notification bar on tablet because of the lack of hardware buttons. I just didn't think about that. Anyway, in the case of the TF101 it returns a resolution of 1280x752 so about 1.702 (80 : 47) ratio. If I use a suitable unit size, like 33.5 or 11.75 vertically I get the proper scaling and this seems to fix the problem of skewed pixels.

Also, while this is good for the TF101 tablet in my case it's not really a great solution. Here is a Gemserk series that talks about a nice solution.

http://blog.gemserk.com/2013/01/22/our-solution-to-handle-multiple-screen-sizes-in-android-part-one/